# animategraphics only produces a still image on overleaf

Tags: overleaf, animations, animate

I'm trying to combine a series of 13 .png files together to create a gif on Overleaf for my dissertation. I have tried a number of things and the best code I can come up with for the actual animation is

```
\animategraphics[loop,width=380]{4}{gif/image-}{1}{13}
```

as this does not produce any errors, and the output pdf produces a still image rather than the standard error text. To clarify, I have a folder named gif containing the files 'image-1.png', 'image-2.png', and so on.

This produces only a still image in the preview pane of overleaf which I initially thought might be a limitation of the platform so I opened up the document in Okular, which supports animated pdf files, and no dice.

I'm using the Institute of Physics template: "https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/author-guidelines-for-publishing-to-iop-publishing-journals-in-latex/dbftskdgszdz"
and had thought that this might cause some issues, however, I have no evidence to back up that claim.

Here is a brief summary of my main.tex document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}
\newcommand{\gguide}{{\it Preparing graphics for IOP Publishing journals}} 

\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}

\animategraphics[loop,width=380]{4}{gif/image-}{1}{13}

\end{document}
```

I have excluded all of the text along with the abstract and my other figures, I would hope to have this in a figure in the future, but I just wanted to get it working first.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be more than welcome.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) If you think the problem is related to Overleaf rather than a general problem, it's best to write us at Overleaf support. If the problem is not Overleaf-specific, you can remove the overleaf tag. In this case you haven't shared your image files with us, but this setup worked alright for me: https://www.overleaf.com/read/yqnjsyrbwnfj Animation tested in Adobe Acrobat Pro and Adobe Acrobat Reader; it plays in both of these viewers. (I don't have Okular installed here.)

Comment: @PaulGessler I had avoided Adobe thinking that it is all pay-to-use, however, after installing Acrobat Reader I can see that it does indeed work. I think I'm going to put a note in my appendix noting that the gifs are viewable in Acrobat Reader if not elsewhere. Thank you very much for taking the effort to look at this, I really appreciate it.